# postman javascript validate key value pairs

Tags: javascript, postman

This the response for GET

```
"items": [
        {
            "itemId": "1234566",
            "weather": "temperature.value > 20 "
        }
```

I would like to add test case

```
var jsonData1 = pm.response.json();
for(var i=0; i<jsonData1.items.length; i++)
{
    if (jsonData.items[i].itemId===newItemId)
    {

if (jsonData.items[i].weather==="temperature.value > 20")
{

       pm.test("weather Update is Sucssesful");
    }   
​
}
}
```

this fails with invalid token error

newItemId is the environment variable saved from POST

Comment: Which variable is your data being held? `jsonData` or `responseBody`?

Comment: It's totally unclear what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this:

```
pm.test("Your test name", function () {
  var checkId = pm.environment.get("newId");
  const jsonData = pm.response.json();
  const item = jsonData.find(i=>i.itemId===checkId);
  pm.expect(item.weatherItem).to.eql("temperature > 20 ");
});
```

Comment: thanks for the response when I try above code I get testing | TypeError: jsonData.find is not a function

Comment: @Kanna Maybe it's `jsonData.Items.find`